# Do Enemies Ever Drop Beds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing on a SMP server, killing mobs, when I found a bed in my inventory that was not there before.

Is it possible that a mob dropped it? I guess I could have randomly picked up a bed but I wasn't near any other players or anything like that. I checked on the minecraft wiki but didn't see any mention of this.

The types of mobs I killed included skeletons, zombies, spiders, and one enderman. Version 1.2.4

Comment: I don't think enemies ever drop craftable items like that.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes they do, and they have since 1.2. See also: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Drops

Comment: I'm just gonna say that Endermen can't pick up beds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Minecraft Wiki has a [table of common and rare drops](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drops#Table_of_drops) for mobs. None them seem to drop beds, and I've certainly never heard of such a thing happening either. I suspect you just managed to pick one up from somewhere without noticing.

Comment: Probably, it just seemed odd as I wasn't even near a bed that I knew of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I seriously doubt it. I have never found a bed, ever. Neither has my brother. And no-where online have I found any evidence of anyone else 'finding' a bed. Also it seems very unlikely because they are crafted, and not some bare-bones item... Sorry. maybe you accidentally hit and picked up your bed?

Comment: It certainly wasn't my bed, but it is multiplayer so it's quite possible